# Magento2 - How to move Cart Items below the Order Summary on checkout page?

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout

I want to show `cart items` outside the `order summary` section  on the `checkout page`.. (e.g - at the bottom of every section in sidebar like - order summary, shipping-information)

[image]

**See my code but it's not working --**

create a `di.xml` file at the location,

**app/code/Vishal/CartItemsAfterSummary/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <!-- Set Billing address above the payment method plugin -->
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="move_billing_address_above_payment_method"
                type="Vishal/CartItemsAfterSummary\Plugin\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Based on the XML file, Create a Plugin Class, **app/code/Vishal/CartItemsAfterSummary/Plugin/Block/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php**

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vishal\CartItemsAfterSummary\Plugin\Block\Checkout;

use Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor as CheckoutLayoutProcessor;

/**
 * Move Billing address to top
 */
class LayoutProcessor
{
    /**
     * @param CheckoutLayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        CheckoutLayoutProcessor $subject,
        array $jsLayout
    ): array {

        $sidebarLayout = $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['sidebar'];

        if (isset($sidebarLayout['children']['summary']['children']['cart_items'])) {
            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['sidebar']['children']['cart_items'] = $sidebarLayout['children']['summary']['children']['cart_items'];

            unset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['sidebar']['children']['summary']['children']['cart_items']);
        }
        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't do it like this because there is no such element under checkout layout to assign a component under checkout->sidebar->cart_items . But one quick question, isn't it already coming under the order totals secion in a default luma theme?

Comment: @ManafPM thanks for your comment but actually i want to show 'cart items' outside the order summary section. (e.g - at the bottom of every section in sidebar like - order summary, shipping-information)

Comment: for that you first need to override the related html file of that secion and add a new region there. This region should be referred inside a checkout_index_index.xml file in your custom module. There you need to add the components to display the cart items summary either via layout processor or via a ui component

Comment: @ManafPM can you post the actual code if possible. what needs to be done.